# Unfortunately, MyApplication has stopped (AndroidStudio Emulator)

Tags: java, android, emulation

I´m new to Android programming but I have some experiences in Java and I have a Problem with my emulator. I use a Nexus 5 emulator in AndroidStudio on a Macbook with OS X 10.9.3

I tried to solve this Problem by my own but I had no luck. I also searched for this Problem but there´s no solution for my problem.

Here´s my code: (in activity_main)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Here´s the MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("First");
    TabHost.TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second");
    TabHost.TabSpec tab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third");
    TabHost.TabSpec tab4 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Fourth");
    TabHost.TabSpec tab5 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Fifth");

    tab1.setIndicator("Tab1");
    tab1.setContent(new Intent(this, Friends.class));
    tab2.setIndicator("Tab2");
    tab2.setContent(new Intent(this, Map.class));
    tab3.setIndicator("Tab3");
    tab3.setContent(new Intent(this, Camera.class));
    tab4.setIndicator("Tab4");
    tab4.setContent(new Intent(this, Map.class));
    tab5.setIndicator("Tab5");
    tab5.setContent(new Intent(this, Profile.class));

    tabHost.addTab(tab1); //editor: This should be the line that throws exception
    tabHost.addTab(tab2);
    tabHost.addTab(tab3);
    tabHost.addTab(tab4);
    tabHost.addTab(tab5);
}
```

Last but not least my log cat:

```
07-30 07:16:55.590      829-829/com.SimonLindmayr.myapplication5.app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-30 07:16:55.590      829-829/com.SimonLindmayr.myapplication5.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a90ba8)
07-30 07:16:55.610      829-829/com.SimonLindmayr.myapplication5.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.SimonLindmayr.myapplication5.app, PID: 829
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.SimonLindmayr.myapplication5.app/com.SimonLindmayr.myapplication5.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:236)
            at com.SimonLindmayr.myapplication5.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 07:21:56.244      829-829/com.SimonLindmayr.myapplication5.app I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 829 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Could you mark the line that is `com.SimonLindmayr.myapplication5.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)`

Comment: And are you sure (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost); doesn't return null

Comment: try this........ TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); ---- but make sure that your layout (activity_main.xml) contains tabhost..

Comment: @stealthjong If so then it would have thrown exception on `tabHost.newTabSpec("First");`

Answer (score 0):

You should not define ids for components  like that , Because if you define like that it will search for predefined ids in android library .If that is not exists it will throw null pointer exception. So you should define id like android:id = "@+id/id_name".